# MacBook Pro (13" 2017 2TDB3) won't power up

Tags: usb, hardware

My 2 weeks old computer doesn't power up anymore! After unplugging it from USB-C docking station I'm not able to get it working again - no sound, picture, connection.

Here is what I've tried:

- hold the power button for ~10s, then pressing it again
- hold Option+Cmd+Shift+Alt and press power for ~10s
- hit the computer hard (this is how I usually repair stuff)
- verify that the power adapter is working correctly
- call support

Nothing helped :(

Answer (score 0):

After giving up and having a beer I decided to give it last try.

**I've opened the lid and started pressing the power button like crazy (~6Hz = ~6 times a sec).**

After 5s I've noticed the backlight to turn on and after few seconds the sleeping beauty woke up like nothing ever happened! Since then, everything is fine..

I'm happy, but scared at the same time as

1. I don't know what caused this issue
2. how I fixed it
3. why holding the power button for ~10s didn't have any effect